# AKS upgrade failed due to usage of a deprecated API but I don't see that API being used

Tags: azure-aks

I am doing an AKS Upgrade in the Azure Portal from 1.25.6 to 1.26.12. It fails because it says I am using a deprecated API, "usage has been detected on API autoscaling.horizontalpodautoscalers.v2beta2.watch". However, I don't see that API in my cluster so why is this happening? I know I can force the upgrade if I need to but I want to resolve this instead of taking that risk.

Here's the full log error message:

```
Failed to save Kubernetes service 'devtest-us1'. Error: Control Plane upgrade is blocked due to recent usage of a Kubernetes API deprecated in the specified version. Please refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide to migrate the usage. To bypass this error, set forceUpgrade in upgradeSettings.overrideSettings. Bypassing this error without migrating usage will result in the deprecated Kubernetes API calls failing. See details in https://aka.ms/aks/UpgradeAndDeprecatedAPIs. Usage details: 1 error occurred:
    * usage has been detected on API autoscaling.horizontalpodautoscalers.v2beta2.watch, and was recently seen at: 2024-03-07 15:46:48 +0000 UTC, which will be removed in 1.26
```

Here's how I checked for the deprecated API. I thought I would see `horizontalpodautoscalers.v2beta2.watch` in both of these if it was in use.

```
~ using ☁️ Production devtest-us1
➜ kubectl get horizontalpodautoscalers -A -o custom-columns='NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,API_VERSION:.apiVersion'
NAMESPACE            NAME                    API_VERSION
datadog-operator     datadog-cluster-agent   autoscaling/v2
kube-state-metrics   kube-state-metrics      autoscaling/v2
kube-system          osm-controller-hpa      autoscaling/v2
kube-system          osm-injector-hpa        autoscaling/v2

➜ kubectl api-resources | grep autoscaling
horizontalpodautoscalers                   hpa                      autoscaling/v2                                         true         HorizontalPodAutoscaler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you received indicates that usage of the deprecated API `autoscaling.horizontalpodautoscalers.v2beta2.watch` was detected in your cluster. However, this message doesn't necessarily mean you have resources currently deployed that use the deprecated API, but rather that there has been recent activity which could include operations like `watch` that are still pointing to the deprecated version of the API. While you did not see this API in the output of your `kubectl` command, it is possible that it was used within the past 12 hours, which is the time frame within which AKS records usage of deprecated APIs. If you are certain that this API is not in use, you can bypass the validation by setting the `forceUpgrade` flag in `upgradeSettings.overrideSettings`

*Now if at all there is a depricated API there*,
you can remove it.
In your aks cluster goto Diagnose and solve problems. Navigate to the Create, Upgrade, Delete, and Scale category, and select Kubernetes API deprecations.
[image]

If there is at all any depricated api, aks will show you
[image]

If there is a deprecated api in your case which is showing here, then wait 12 hours from the time the last deprecated API usage was seen and retry your cluster upgrade. You can also check past API usage by enabling [Container Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-query#resource-logs) and exploring kube audit logs.
Here's how you can perform you aks cluster upgrade by
[Bypassing validation to ignore API changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/stop-cluster-upgrade-api-breaking-changes#bypass-validation-to-ignore-api-changes)

```
az aks update --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup --enable-force-upgrade --upgrade-override-until 2023-10-01T13:00:00Z
```

[image]

Once the above command has succeeded, you can retry the upgrade operation.

```
az aks upgrade --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup  --kubernetes-version <yourchoiceofversion>
```

[image]

Done

[image]

References:

- [Stop Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster upgrades automatically on API breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/stop-cluster-upgrade-api-breaking-changes#mitigate-stopped-upgrade-operations)
- [Kubernetes API Concepts - Watching Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#watching-resources)